# How do you change opacity of grease pencil strokes in blender 2.8?

Tags: grease-pencil, versions, 2d

I actually have 2 questions, how do you change the grease pencil opacity and how do add another layer? The old grease pencil supported layers but now it's a grease pencil object, how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I guess I am going to answer my own question. Because grease pencil is its own object now the color palette is no longer there, each grease pencil object will have its own material. If you want to lower the opacity you have to go Materials and under stroke click on color and lower the alpha channel. As for making new layers, you can just make new keyframes.

Edited: I was mistaken there is another way to decrease the opacity, if you click on the grease pencil icon on the left side of the material tab you can also see the old layer opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for folks having this problem: I thought the opacity of my strokes was low but couldn't figure out any explanation. Then I realized it was because I had the radius set too low; I turned it up, and while it didn't appear to increase the width of the stroke (at least from the distance at which I was viewing the stroke), it did make it a lot darker.